# Find client certificate information from server in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I'm programming an application that uses a SSL connection to ensure only valid clients connect (using client certificates).  Is there some API call the server can call on a connection to retrieve information about the certificate the client used?

Comment: The server is an C++ application I wrote that is what the client connects to.  I'm hoping there's some way of accessing the information programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SSL_get_peer_certificate](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_peer_certificate.html) method.