# How to get the CA Certificate Used to Validate Client Certificate programmatically

Tags: c++, openssl

In a server application, once a connection has been established I can grab the client certificate from the `SSL *` I have. Is there a way to find out which CA I used to validate that certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SSL_get0_verified_chain()` function for this purpose. See the documentation here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get0_verified_chain.html

Note that this function was first introduced in OpenSSL 1.1.0, so this won't work in OpenSSL 1.0.2.

Comment: What about older versions?

Answer (score 1):

This post seems on point:
[Find client certificate information from server in OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306427/find-client-certificate-information-from-server-in-openssl?rq=1)

Since [SSL_get_peer_certificate](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_peer_certificate.html) returns an `X509` cert, I would expect that the cert chain would be included (you couldn't handle a CRL properly without it, I'd think)?